# Как правильно через js получить высоту блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь получить высоту блока через js. Но высота вычисленная с использованием js отличается от той, которая указывается в браузере. Объясните пожалуйста почему так.

[image: Консоль разработчика]

Для получения высоты блока использовал такие методы:

```
  var trackHeight = $(".slick-track").height();
  var trackInnerHeight = $(".slick-track").innerHeight();
  var trackOuterHeight = $(".slick-track").outerHeight();
  var trackOuterHeightTrue = $(".slick-track").outerHeight(true);

  console.log("Высота .slick-track:");
  console.log("height() " + trackHeight);
  console.log("innerHeight() " + trackInnerHeight);
  console.log("outerHeight() " + trackOuterHeight);
  console.log("outerHeight(true) " + trackOuterHeightTrue);
```

Answer (score 2):

**На javascript:**

```js
// var foo = document.getElementById('block').clientHeight;
// var foo = document.getElementById('block').offsetHeight;
var foo = document.getElementById('block').scrollHeight;

console.log(foo);
```

```css
#block {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

**clientHeight** высота содержимого вместе с полями **padding**, но без полосы прокрутки.

**offsetHeight** «внешняя» высота блока, включая рамки.

**scrollHeight** полная внутренняя высота, включая прокрученную область.

**Либо ещё можно так (через getComputedStyle):**

*P.S. [Ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes) на изучение*

```js
var foo = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("block"));

console.log(foo.height);
```

```css
#block {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

**На jQuery:**

```js
console.log($("#block").height());
```

```css
#block {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
```